# Can i decode Any escaped expression using JSON.parse?

Tags: javascript, json

```
//test expression 1
\uD798\uB4E0 \uC2DC\uAE30\uC5D0 \uC2DC \uD55C \uD3B8\uC774 \uD070 \uC704\uB85C\uAC00 \uB418\uAE30\uB3C4 \uD569\uB2C8\uB2E4. \uADF8\uB7F0 \uC758\uBBF8\uC5D0\uC11C \uC774 \uCC45\uC740 \uB9CE\uC740 \uC0AC\uB78C\uB4E4\uC5D0\uAC8C \uC704\uB85C\uC640 \uB530\uB73B\uD568\uC774 \uB420 \uCC45\uC774\uB77C\uB294 \uC0DD\uAC01\uC774 \uB4ED\uB2C8\uB2E4. \uCC98\uC74C\uC5D0\uB294 \uB4DC\uB77C\uB9C8\uB97C \uBCF4\uACE0 \uAD6C\uC785\uD558\uAC8C \uB418\uC5C8\uB294\uB370 \uADF8\uB0E5 \uC2DC\uC9D1\uC778 \uC904 \uC54C\uC558\uC2B5\uB2C8\uB2E4. \uBC1B\uC544\uBCF4\uB2C8 \uC67C\uCABD\uC5D0\uB294 \uC2DC\uAC00 \uC368 \uC788\uACE0 \uC624\uB978\uCABD\uC5D0\uB294 \uB3C5\uC790\uAC00 \uC9C1\uC811 \uC2DC\uB97C \uC4F0\uB294 \uD615\uC2DD\uC774\uC5C8\uC2B5\uB2C8\uB2E4. \uC2DC\uB97C \uC77D\uACE0 \uC74C\uBBF8\uD558\uBA74\uC11C \uC2DC\uB97C \uC368 \uB0B4\uB824\uAC00\uB294\uB370 \uADF8 \uB3D9\uC548 \uB290\uAEF4\uBCF4\uC9C0 \uBABB\uD55C \uC704\uB85C\uC640 \uD3C9\uC548\uC744 \uB290\uB07C\uAC8C \uB418\uC5C8\uC2B5\uB2C8\uB2E4. \uC694\uC998\uCC98\uB7FC \uC190\uAE00\uC528\uB97C \uC4F0\uB294 \uAC83\uC774 \uC27D\uC9C0 \uC54A\uC740 \uC2DC\uB300\uC5D0 \uC774\uB807\uAC8C \uC190\uC73C\uB85C \uC9C1\uC811 \uC8FC\uC625\uAC19\uC740 \uC2DC\uB4E4\uC744 \uC190\uC73C\uB85C \uC368 \uBCF4\uB294 \uAC83 \uC790\uCCB4\uAC00 \uD790\uB9C1\uC774 \uB418\uB294 \uAC83 \uAC19\uC2B5\uB2C8\uB2E4

//test expression 2
uAC00\uB054\uC740 \uC2DC \uAC19\uC740 \uAC83\uC744 \uC4F0\uBA74 \uB9C8\uC74C \uC548\uC815\uC774 \uB41C\uB2E4\uB294 \uC18C\uB9AC\uB97C \uB4E3\uB294\uB2E4.  \uC194\uC9C1\uD788 \uC2DC\uB97C \uBCC4\uB85C \uC88B\uC544\uD558\uC9C0 \uC54A\uACE0, \uADF8\uB9AC \uBCF4\uACE0 \uC2F6\uC740 \uC874\uC7AC\uB3C4 \uC544\uB2C8\uB2E4.  \uB3C4\uAE68\uBE44\uB97C \uC5F4\uC815\uC801\uC73C\uB85C \uC2DC\uCCAD\uD558\uB358 \uC5B4\uB290 \uB0A0 \uC2DC\uAC00 \uAC00\uB4DD \uB2F4\uAE34 \uC774 \uCC45\uC744 \uBCF4\uC558\uB2E4.  \uC640\uB2FF\uC558\uB2E4 \uD0DC\uC5B4\uB098\uC11C \uCC98\uC74C\uC73C\uB85C \uC2DC\uC758 \uB2F4\uAE34 \uB0B4\uC6A9\uC774 \uC640\uB2FF\uC740 \uC801\uC740 \uCC98\uC74C\uC774\uB2E4.  \uB3C4\uAE68\uBE44 \uB54C\uBB38\uC774 \uC544\uB2C8\uB2E4 \uC2DC\uC758 \uADF8 \uAD6C\uC808 \uD558\uB098\uD558\uB098\uAC00 \uC644\uBCBD\uD574\uBCF4\uC600\uB2E4.  &nbsp;  \uBC14\uB85C \uAD6C\uC785\uD574 \uD558\uB098\uD558\uB098 \uBA3C\uC800 \uC77D\uC5B4\uBCF4\uC558\uB2E4.   \uC815\uB9D0 \uB3C4\uAE68\uBE44\uC5D0\uC11C \uB098\uC628 \uD558\uB098\uC758 \uC2DC\uBFD0\uB9CC \uC544\uB2C8\uB77C \uB098\uBA38\uC9C0 \uC2DC\uB4E4\uB3C4 \uD558\uB098\uAC19\uC774 \uBCF4\uAE30 \uC88B\uC740 \uC2DC\uB4E4,&nbsp;\uADF8\uB0E5 \uC2DC\uAC04\uB0A0 \uB54C \uD55C\uBC88\uCBE4 \uC77D\uC5B4\uBCF4\uBA74 \uC88B\uC740 \uC2DC\uB4E4\uC774 \uAC00\uB4DD\uD588\uB2E4.  &nbsp;  \uB610, \uB354 \uC88B\uC740 \uBD80\uBD84\uC740 \uC624\uB978\uCABD \uC885\uC774\uC5D0 \uB0B4\uAC00, \uB098\uC758 \uB290\uB08C\uB300\uB85C \uADF8 \uC2DC\uB97C \uC4F8 \uC218 \uC788\uB2E4\uB294 \uAC83. \uB108\uBB34 \uC88B\uC558\uB2E4. \uD56D\uC0C1 \uD558\uB098\uC529 \uC4F4\uB2E4. \uB9C8\uC74C \uC9C4\uC815\uB418\uACE0 \uADF8 \uC2DC\uC778\uC758 \uB290\uB08C\uC774 \uC544\uB2C8

//test expression 3
\uBC29\uC1A1\uC791\uAC00\uB97C \uAFC8\uAFB8\uB294 \uC870\uCE74\uC5D0\uAC8C \uC120\uBB3C\uD55C \uCC45.&nbsp;  \uB108\uB098\uC5C6\uC774 \uB4DC\uB77C\uB9C8 \'\uB3C4\uAE68\uBE44\'\uC5D0 \uBE60\uC9C4 \uC2DC\uAE30\uC640 \uB9DE\uBB3C\uB824&nbsp;  \'\uC0AC\uB791\uC758 \uBB3C\uB9AC\uD559\' \uB355\uBD84\uC5D0\uB3C4 \uB9DD\uC124\uC774\uC9C0 \uC54A\uACE0 \uCC45\uC744 \uC9D1\uC5B4\uB4E4\uC5C8\uB2E4.  \uC120\uBB3C\uC744 \uD558\uBA70,   \uACE0\uB4F1\uD559\uAD50 \uC785\uD559\uC744 \uC55E\uB454 \uC870\uCE74\uC5D0\uAC8C\uB294   \uC5B4\uB5A4 \uC2DC\uB4E4\uC774 \uBCC4\uCC98\uB7FC \uB9C8\uC74C\uC5D0 \uBC15\uD790\uAE4C \uAD81\uAE08\uD588\uB2E4.  &nbsp;  \uC774\uBAA8\uC758 \uB9C8\uC74C\uC744 \uC54C\uC558\uB294\uC9C0   \uC5BC\uB9C8 \uC804 \uC870\uCE74\uB294 \"\uB108\uBB34 \uC88B\uB2E4\"\uBA70   \uD544\uC0AC\uD55C \uD754\uC801\uC744 \uB2F4\uC544&nbsp;\uCE74\uD1A1\uC73C\uB85C \uC0AC\uC9C4\uC744 \uBCF4\uB0B4\uC654\uB2E4.   \uBC1C\uD0C1\uB41C \uC2DC\uB294 \uAE40\uACBD\uBBF8 \uC2DC\uC778\uC758 \'\uCD08\uC2B9\uB2EC\'.  \"\uC587\uACE0 \uAE34 \uC785\uC220 \uD558\uB098\uB85C/\uC628 \uBC24\uD558\uB298 \uB2E4 \uBB3C\uACE0 \uAC00\uB294/\uAC80\uC740 \uBB3C\uACE0\uAE30 \uD55C \uB9C8\uB9AC//  \uC678\uBFD4 \uD558\uB098\uC5D0/ \uC628 \uBAB8 \uB2E4 \uB04C\uB824\uAC00\uB294 \uAC80\uC740 \uCF54\uBFD4\uC18C \uD55C \uB9C8\uB9AC//  \uAC00\uB2E4\uAC00 \uC7A0\uC2DC \uBA48\uCDB0\uC120 \uAC80\uC815\uACE0\uC591\uC774/\uC785\uC5D0 \uBB3C\uB9B0/\uC0DD\uC120\uCC98\uB7FC \uD30C\uB2E5\uC774\uB294/ \uC740\uC0C9 \uB098\uBB47\uC78E \uD55C \uC7A5//  \uAC80\uC815 \uADF8\uBB3C\uCF54\uB9C8\uB2E4 \uADC0 \uC7A1\uD78C \uBCC4\uBE5B\uB4E4//  \uB098\uB3C4
```

I applied `JSON.parse('["' + expression + '"]')`, it's not working. I want to decode these expression. They can include any special characters. so it's hard maybe.

Comment: You could just use them as they are. Doesn't that work?

Comment: What do you mean by “it's not working”? With your JSON.parse statement, you create an array with one string element, which is your expression. JSON.parse will not decode the unicode characters in the strings, if that's what you're thinking.

Comment: @PatrickHund you can decode `JSON.parse('["' + "\\uD798\\uB4E0 \\uC2DC\\uAE30\\uC5D0" + '"]')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following:

```js
const str = "\\uD798\\uB4E0 \\uC2DC\\uAE30\\uC5D0"

console.log(eval('"' + str + '"'));
```

Comment: It's not just unicode string. it was escaped. so `\\uD798\\uB4E0 \\uC2DC\\uAE30\\uC5D0`

Comment: Then just `eval` it.

Comment: The expression is sent by browser client user. Can I(server) use it?(for security)

Comment: Why is the browser/client sending such a string?

Comment: Choosing What browser sends is not my right. Just Another server sends such a string.(Actually, the server(DWR) sends the **javascript code** to my server.). For example, `var a = {}; a.content="\uD798\uB4E0 \uC2DC\uAE30\uC5D0(but this is what client sends. so i can't use eval." ...etc` So i catched a string using regular expression, now i want to parse the encoded string to general string.. for now, i resolved this using try- catch execption...